# Do I need to recheck my luggage during transit at Dubai?

Tags: transit, dxb

I'm travelling from KTM to Dubai (DXB) (Terminal 2) through Emirates 737 operated by Flydubai. I then fly out to JFK from Terminal 3 on Emirates Airbus A700_800.

Should I collect my baggage myself during transit at Dubai or do the airlines manage my luggage to my final destination?

Answer (score 1):

If you booked a single booking with Emirates, with flights on Emirates and flydubai, your baggage [will be checked through](https://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/connecting_with_flydubai/) to your final destination.

> If you’re travelling from an Emirates destination and connecting onto flydubai, your baggage will be checked through to your final destination.
>
> If you’re travelling from a flydubai destination and connecting onto Emirates, your baggage will be checked through to your final destination.